# Running pdflatex twice by default in WinEdt 6

Tags: pdftex, winedt

Is it possible to use a switch or some other change for pdflatex, so that it always compiles twice?

Because of the changes to the toc and labels, two runs are often necessary. As running twice does not hurt as far as I'm aware, I'd like to standardize that behaviour.

Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find a relevant switch myself.

Comment: You can use `latexmk` with WinEdt to run the pdflatex.  Latexmk runs the appropriate amount times to square toc, references, bib, etc.  Here is a link to `latexmk` http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/

Comment: What is latexmk? I'm using winedt 6.0 on windows, but I can't find a latexmk option. EDIT: ok i see from the link, I'd prefer to do it from within WinEdt if possible though, so I can keep using it for compiling.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary; TOC and cross-references eventually stabilize, during document preparation it's not needed to have them correct all the time.

Comment: You would still be using WinEdt.  Latexmk would take over the compiling via a perl script.  Nothing would change on how you compile with your current program.

Comment: Use 'pdflatexify'. It will take care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Harish has partially already answered in his comment (`PDFLaTeXify` comes from the LaTeXify addon which is not available for WinEdt 6), I'll give you a more detailed answer.

The button `PDFTeXify` (or `TeXify` when you want a dvi workflow) launches an algorithm that takes care of compiling the document itself, as well as bibliographies, indexes, glossaries, etc., to get a fully compiled document.

In other words, it launches `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `makeindex` as many times as needed for a complete compilation.

If I can make a suggestion, upgrade to WinEdt 8 which is Unicode capable and has a lot of new features.

Also note that you can still use the button `PDFLaTeX` to merely launch `pdflatex` once, when the compilation of bibliographies, indexes, etc. is not needed.

Comment: It was my understanding that WinEdt 6 and 7 or not backwards compatibel with each other. So thats not really an option for me. I didn't know that about PDFTeXiFy, lets see if that works :-)

Comment: Be sure that it works... If you want to contact me privately, I'll tell you how to migrate to WinEdt 8.

Comment: That would be great, but I can't find a private contact option on stackexchange

Comment: Have a look at http://www.winedt.org/, select one of my addons and the end of the page you will find the contact.